# What does MailChimp error code -100 mean?

Tags: mailchimp

Had an application using the /lists/subscribe endpoint of the [MailChimp API](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/) (<strike>v1.3</strike> v2.0) that was returning a "-100" error code for a particular address for a time (but it's cleared now.)

This isn't in their [list of exceptions](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/exceptions.field.php) – anyone seen this before and know if it might indicate anything useful? Or if it's in that range, but not on the list of "known exceptions", does that just mean an unknown server error?

I'm using [this PHP library](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) to talk to the API.

(Of course if I can get an answer MailChimp themselves I'll update this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lists/subscribe](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) is actually a v2.0 call. The v1.3 equivalent is [listSubscribe](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php). -100 is, IIRC, a validation error and it should come with more description about what specifically the problem was with your submission.

A common validation issue with subscribe calls is passing the email address as a string instead of a JSON Object. This, for example, will return an error:

```
{
    "email": "some.person@somedomain.com"
    ...
}
```

Instead, you'd want:

```
{
    "email": { "email": "some.person@somedomain.com" }
    ...
}
```

It's a common problem because it's kind of silly to require that format, but that is what's required nonetheless. There are a billion other ways to get validation errors, of course, but that's a good one to double-check.

Comment: It's not specifically that (remember that tripping me up the first time I used the API), but thanks, that's very helpful.